# getting error as "Failed to find user name [WORKGROUP\SYSTEM]" during informatica installation

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

Getting above error in the logs, while installing informatica server 10.4, this is happening while i am in the create domain menu

[image: informatica domain creation]

then i get this error
[image: error]

when i check the logs, I am seeing this error.

OutPut : [ICMD_10033] Command [generateEncryptionKey] failed with error [[INFASETUP_10000] [FrameworkUtils_0006] The encryption key file cannot be generated. [[FrameworkUtils_0022] Failed to find user name [WORKGROUP\SYSTEM] during Informatica service startup, and so cannot grant read and write permissions on the node configuration directory to the user. Verify that the user that started the Informatica service is valid. If you are a Local System User, you can ignore this message as you inherit the read-write permissions.]..].

I am not getting where this [WORKGROUP\SYSTEM] user name is coming up

Comment: i think you are trying to install in Windows? If yes, make sure the user you are using have admin permissions. this message `failed during Informatica service startup` will tell you that the installation user doesnt have permission. If you are using admin user, then see if your admin user have access to all folders in that box.

Comment: No actually i am running it as administrator and also i tried running the command from informatica logs, by running the cmd as admin "C:\Informatica\10.4.1\isp\bin\infasetup.bat  generateEncryptionKey -kw ***** -dn "Domain" -kl "C:\Informatica\10.4.1\isp\config\keys"  " but it's still giving the same issue, my user and admin user both have access to all the folders

Comment: either folder doesnt exist or you do not have access

Comment: both the folders are present. In the error it says "Failed to find user name [WORKGROUP\SYSTEM] during Informatica service startup", means it is trying to find the wrong user name, there will be no user name as [WORKGROUP\SYSTEM]

Comment: can you check if it created any new services ? if yes, you can make sure its running under admin user and retry

Comment: No it has not created any new services, because it is failing during domain creation.